# JQuery code problem?

Tags: jquery, html

New to JQuery, I added the following JQuery code below and moved it around in my code and now it won't work I forgot what I did, can someone fix my code by placing the below code in its correct place thanks.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('#changes-saved').remove();
});
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

JQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#changes-saved').hide();
    $('.save-button').click(function() {
        $.post($('#contact-form').attr('action'), $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(html) {
            $('div.contact-info-form').html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('Changes saved!').show().pause(1000).hide();
        });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('#changes-saved').remove();
    });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an extra paste resulting in an extra return and closing block, just remove this at the end:

```
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `<a>` from propagating in the browser.

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    if (!event) event = window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault)
       event.preventDefault();
    else
       event.returnValue = false;


    $('#changes-saved').remove();

    //In case the event propagation didn't work....(mostly dumb IE)
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

---

From your code, just fix

```
$(function() {
    $('#changes-saved').hide();
    $('.save-button').click(function() {
        $.post($('#contact-form').attr('action'), $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(html) {
            $('div.contact-info-form').html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('Changes saved!').show().pause(1000).hide();
        });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('#changes-saved').remove();
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? Had an extra `)};` at the end and `return false;` was not inside the click event handler function.

```
$(function() {
    $('#changes-saved').hide();

    $('.save-button').click(function() {
        $.post(
            $('#contact-form').attr('action'), 
            $('#contact-form').serialize(), 
            function(html) {
                $('div.contact-info-form').html(html);
                $('#changes-saved').append('Changes saved!')
                    .show().pause(1000).hide();
            }
        );

        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('#changes-saved').remove();

        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```